# Why CopyOnWriteArrayList use ReentrantLock but ReentrantReadWriteLock?

Tags: java, copyonwritearraylist

This is the code to add the element, Why not use ReentrantReadWriteLock but ReentrantLock

```
 public boolean add(E e) {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
               //add element 
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why does it need a read/write lock, which is more complicated?  Why bother?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` implementation is that read operations do not do any locking at all.

So since only write operations need locking, and they all need to acquire an exclusive lock, it it simpler and more efficient to use the `ReentrantLock` class here.

Comment: After listening to your explanation, and seeing the Lock interface, and the ReadWriteLock interface, I understand the difference between them. Thank you for your help. Good day